# read() after select() blocking when reading from pipe from spawned process

Tags: c++, unix

There are 3 pipe calls to create stdin, stdout, stderr for a a new process. fork() is called, the exec() is called. This wrapped up in a popen2 function which works.

When using this popen2 function, reading from stdout from the new process blocks on read(), even after select() returns that read is ready to read. I expect it to be able to read(). My only guess is that read() for this fd is trying to fill the input buf.

One exception: if stdin is closed, stdout is closed by the child process and the read completes even when buf cannot be filled.

What I need is for read() to return what is ready to be read? is the default mode buffered and I don't know it?

```
pid_t popen2(const char *const argv[], int *in, int *out, int *err)
    {
    int res;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    int inpipefd[2];
    int outpipefd[2];
    int errpipefd[2];
    if(0!=pipe(inpipefd)) {
        perror("allocating pipe for child stdin");
        return -1;
    }
    if(0!=pipe(outpipefd)) {
        close(inpipefd[0]);
        close(inpipefd[1]);
        perror("allocating pipe for child stdout");
        return -1;
    }
    if(0!=pipe(errpipefd)) {
        close(inpipefd[0]);
        close(inpipefd[1]);
        close(outpipefd[0]);
        close(outpipefd[1]);
        perror("allocating pipe for child stderr");
        return -1;
    }
    pid = fork();
    if (0==pid) {
        if (-1==dup2(inpipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO)) {exit(errno);}
        if (-1==dup2(outpipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO)) {exit(errno);}
        if (-1==dup2(errpipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO)) {exit(errno);}
        close(inpipefd[0]);
        close(inpipefd[1]);
        close(outpipefd[0]);
        close(outpipefd[1]);
        close(errpipefd[0]);
        close(errpipefd[1]);
        execvp(argv[0], (char* const*)argv);
        perror("exec failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(inpipefd[0]);
    close(outpipefd[1]);
    close(errpipefd[1]);
    *in = inpipefd[1];
    *out = outpipefd[0];
    *err = errpipefd[0];
    return pid;
    }

...
if(0>=(pid = popen2(argv, &in, &out, &err))) {
        return make_unique<std::string>();
    }
    res = writeall(in, cont.c_str(), cont.length());
    if(res==-1) {
        goto err;
    }
    close(in);
...

unique_ptr<std::string> DecryptProcess::Read() {
    auto result = make_unique<std::string>();
    const unsigned int BUFLEN = 1024*16;
    std::vector<char> buf(BUFLEN);
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int n;
    int fcnt;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(out_fd, &rfds);
    FD_SET(err_fd, &rfds);
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 100000;
    fcnt = select(std::max(out_fd, err_fd)+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (fcnt == -1) {
        return result;
        } else if (!fcnt) {
        return result;
        }
    if (FD_ISSET(err_fd, &rfds)) {
        n = read(err_fd, &buf[0], buf.size());
        }
    if (FD_ISSET(out_fd, &rfds)) {
        do
            {
            n = read(out_fd, &buf[0], buf.size());
            if (n == -1) {
                return result;
                }
            if (n>0)
                result->append(buf.cbegin(), buf.cbegin()+n);
            } while ( n > 0 );
        }
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: What OS?  You can try running under something like `strace`/`truss` to see what the `select()` system call actually does.  You might have to add some verbose options.

Comment: If you add a few more debugging prints in your code, it's likely that you will see that your code calls `select()`, then calls `read()` which immediately returns, contrary to your claims. But because of your `while` loop `read()` gets called again, which then blocks.

Comment: `read()` never tries to fill the buffer, it always returns as soon as the device driver has something available.

Comment: @sam omg now I feel dumb. I was looking right passed that. Ty

Comment: `execvp` directly on the args isn't what `popen` classically does, but the fact you are not passing in a command string like how `popen` expects means this has little relationship to `popen`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[deleted the debugging statements which only clutter the view]

```
    if (FD_ISSET(out_fd, &rfds)) {
        do
            {
            n = read(out_fd, &buf[0], buf.size());
            if (n == -1) {
                return result;
                }
            if (n>0)
                result->append(buf.cbegin(), buf.cbegin()+n);
            } while ( n > 0 );
        }
```

Here you're not doing a single `read()`, but doing the `read()` in a loop until it returns an error or hits EOF. So code will loop until it will consume all data already written to the pipe, and then block until more data is written to it. `select()` returning a file as ready for reading only tells that there's *some* data available to be read from it, not that no `read()` will block until EOF.

And btw, `select()` makes **no guarantees** that even a single `read()` on a fd marked as ready for reading will *not* actually block.<sup>[1]</sup> The only way to be sure of that is to set the fd to non-blocking mode (eg. with `fcntl(O_NONBLOCK)`) and check for `errno == EAGAIN` in the error case.

Your code has many other problems (eg. double flushing of stdio buffers, failure to check for `EINTR`, etc).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See the [BUGS section of the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html#BUGS).

Comment: Can you link to background on the other problems? What double flushing of stdio buffers? I was able to find information re: EINTR, but if you have recommended reading, I'd like that.

Comment: Can you provide/link some background information about your statement "`select()` makes **no guarantees** that even a single `read()` on a fd marked as ready for reading will _not_ actually block"?

Comment: @jrwren Wrt double flushing: The exit() from the child will also flush the stdio buffers, which may result in the data put out by any printf(), perror() called before the fork() being written twice.

Comment: @bodo it cannot make such guarantees. the same file object may be read from another process/thread between the select and the read from this thread. And even when that does not happen, select() may still  "spuriously" report a fd as ready when not actually ready, as mentioned in the select(2) man page from Linux.